# AWS: Run a Python script to create a file in S3. No output in S3, but works locally

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I want to run the following `.py` script as a job in AWS Glue Studio. This script was just a test to see if I could get something to work. Basically, I want this `.py` script to run and create a file called `myfile.txt` in my desired `s3` directory. I was able to get this same script to work, locally, but it doesn't produce any output in `s3`.

How can I fix this?

```
import sys
import os

# Specify the path
path = '.'
# path = 's3://test-dir-awsglue/'
  
# Specify the file name
file = 'myfile.txt'

# Creating a file at specified location
with open(os.path.join(path, file), 'w') as fp:
    pass
    # To write data to new file uncomment
    # this fp.write("New file created")
```

The job details are:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image: My permissions:]

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to write an object in S3 using the URI as it is a folder and that is not how to interact with S3.

In order to make an action over S3 you have to use the S3 client or resource through the boto3 library, then call methods that allow you to make some actions like put_object to create/write a file.

Below there is an example on how to write a new file (myFile.txt) through the put_object method; useful documentation at the bottom.

```
import boto3

#A low-level client representing Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3)
client = boto3.client('s3')

response = client.put_object(
    Body=b'This is a test',
    Bucket='my-bucket-stack-test',
    Key='myfile.txt',
)
print(f'Response {response["ResponseMetadata"]["HTTPStatusCode"]}')
```

Output:

```
Response 200
```

1. First import boto3 that would allows to interact with s3
2. Then instantiate the s3 client
3. Next calls the `put_object` method that expects some arguments as:

Body (bytes or seekable file-like object) -- Object data.

Bucket (string) --[REQUIRED] The bucket name to which the PUT action was initiated...

Key (string) --[REQUIRED] Object key for which the PUT action was initiated.

4. It assigns to response the returned values of `put_object` that contains information about the resulting action
5. The response variable is a dict and then it prints the HTTPStatusCode key under ResponseMetadata that show a 200 code response indicating a successful call

Boto3 S3 and put_object method documentation : https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/put_object.html